# How to join multiple tables in postgresql?

Tags: xml, postgresql, view, inner-join, openerp-7

There are tables in my customize project: **account_move_line** >|---||- **account_move** -||---|< **account_invoice** -||---|< **account_invoice_tax**

and here are some of it's definition

```
account_move_line  account_move    account_invoice    account_invoice_tax
-----------------  ------------    ---------------    ------------------- 
   partner_id       partner_id         move_id        base_amount        
   move_id                             partner_id     tax_amount
                                                      name
```

When i try to pull data from account_move_line these are some of the result

```
partner_id     |   move_id   |     credit   ....
10000001            58              28.75   ....
10000001            59              78.25   ....
10000001            28              10.00   ....
10000004            11              12.25   ....
10000002            14              20.20   ....
```

(The origin actually of the credit is the tax_amount in table account_invoice_tax)

**My question is: How can i get the sum of base_amount and tax_amount to which partner_id in account_move_line appears only once?**

What i have done so far are these:

1.I create first view:

```
create or replace view ewt as (           
      select ai.id as id,ai.partner_id as partner_id,
          sum(abs(ait.tax_amount)) as tax_amount,
          sum(ait.base) as base_amount,ait.name 
      from account_invoice ai
      inner join account_invoice_tax ait 
          on ai.id = ait.invoice_id where ait.name like '%EWT%' 
          group by ai.id,ai.partner_id,ait.tax_amount,ait.base,ait.name 
          order by ai.partner_id
)
```

2.I create second view:

```
create or replace view ewt_f as (           
    select ewt.partner_id as id,
           ewt.partner_id as  partner_id,
           sum(ewt.tax_amount) as tax_amount,
           sum(ewt.base_amount) as base_amount,
           ewt.name 
    from ewt group by ewt.partner_id,ewt.name 
    order by (select res.name from customer res 
                 where res.id = ewt.partner_id 
              order by res.name asc) asc 
)
```

and the second one is what i passed on my xml but my sort did not work.
Is it possible to create just one view for that and how? Why my sorting did not work?

My desired output actually is something like this:
(from the result of table view)

```
partner_id    |    base_amount    |   tax_amount ....
10000001              579.00          117.00(from the sum of tax_amount in table account_invoice_tax so does base_amount)      
10000004              250.00          12.25
10000002              150.00          20.20
```

**Any suggestion is much appreciated**

**EDIT**

```
account_move_line (is) many2one (to) account_move
account_move (is) one2many (to) account_invoice
account_invoice (is) one2mny (to) account_invoice_tax

account_invoice_tax has these following columns:
name,
base_amount,
tax_amount,
invoice_id,

account_invoice:
name,
partner_id,
move_id,
...

account_move:
name,
partner_id
...

account_move_line:
partner_id
name
debit
credit
....
```

from that tables and using sql statement, i want to show something like this:

partner_id from account_move_line,sum of base_amount from account_invoice_tax (regardless of it's invoice_id) because the credit or debit in account_move_line is the tax_amount in account_invoice_tax. I'm just having problem on how to pull the base_amount in account_invoice_tax.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your db model correctly. You should try to give a better definition.

But isn't a group by ... having clause what you're looking for ?

```
select partner_id, sum (base_amount + tax_amount)
from account_invoice_tax
group by partner_id
having count(*) = 1
```

EDIT : 
The sameidea with a join would give :

```
select t.partner_id, sum (t.base_amount + t.tax_amount)
from account_invoice_tax t, account_move_line l
where t.partner_id = l.partner_id
group by t.partner_id
having count(*) = 1
```